# Ubercart product quantity count in product view page show as smsung 2/10 sold?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I added a product and say it has count of ten(of that product), If one is bought, then I want to show in the product view page out of 10/1 sold like that.

Is there any contributed modules available, or custom way to do it? I can add the quantity as field in the product content type, but what do I do after that?

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75002/how-to-check-the-stock-count-of-an-ubercart-node

Comment: @Bala: what i want is to do is while adding a product, if enter 10 as the product count, if two are sold of tat products, i want the result to be as 8/2sold like tat in the product view page. I dont know how what your referred answer will help my question. I have not installed any stock module. Clear me if i am wrong.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601667/how-to-show-available-stock-quantity-in-ubercart and http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/5643/stock_level_product_detail_page

Comment: If you want to do it with custom code, then you just create one more custom talbe like tbl_product_stock. There you keep the product quantity. Then the you decrement the value of quantity at each product checkout.

Comment: @Bala: I enabled the stock module, where should i  add the stock value?

Comment: @Bala: but how will i know how much product currently it has been sold ?

Comment: @Ram I'm also trying to search for you since yesterday, once I found it I will let you know

Comment: @Bala: Also there is a issue w.r.t auction where after some one wins auction, only sell price gets added to the ubercart. Since i am already using this module, i am just want to stick with it and resolve or make it work ? any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: @Ram, Check my answer in this question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94204/how-to-configure-stock-module-in-ubercart-and-know-how-many-products-sold-out-of/94206#94206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code snippets to display total and sold item from stock:

```
$output = '';

$array_sku = uc_product_get_models($node->nid, FALSE);          

foreach ($array_sku as $sku) {
    $stock_level = uc_stock_level($sku);

    $stock_counts = db_select('uc_order_products', 'up')
                    ->fields('up', array('nid','qty'))
                    ->condition('up.model', $sku, '=')
                    ->execute()
                    ->fetchAll();

    $quantity_count = 0;

    if(isset($stock_counts))  {   
        foreach($stock_counts as $stock_count ) {
            $quantity_count += $stock_count->qty;
        }   
    }

    $total = $stock_level +  $quantity_count;

    if($total == 0){
        $total = 1;
    }           

    $output .= $total . " / " . $quantity_count . " Sold out";          
  }

 print $output;
```

Kindly see that above code will be check stock level for each different `SKU` of the product. If there is attribute of the product and each attribute has different `SKU`, then it will display the `stock` for each `sKU` of the product.

It will work perfect in fresh "Ubercart" installation with "stock" configuration.

You can add this code in `node--product.tpl.php` file in your theme directory.

Comment: Actually there is a bug in this code, i found out. The issue was this is only chekcing row count of the nid and no quantity check. So for a record if i order 3 of that products , still row count wil be only one not three... I am updating the answer.

Comment: I have posted the answer. You can update your answer too. i am not going to un-check your answer, so better you update your answer

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but you can find the stock level using the below code, just put in the node.tpl.php, and print the var $stock_html in a proper place, probably in node-product.tpl.php `<?php print $stock_html ?>`  .

```
<?php
if ($node->type == 'product') {
  $arr_sku = uc_stock_skus($node->nid);
  $stock_html .='<table>';
  foreach($arr_sku as $sku){
    $stocklevel = uc_stock_level($sku);
    if ($stocklevel) {
      if ($stocklevel < 1) {
        $stocklevel = '<span class="nostock">'.$stocklevel.'</span>';
      }
      $stock_html .='<tr><td>'.$sku.'</td><td>:&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$stocklevel.'</td></tr>';
    }
  }
  $stock_html .='</table>';
}
?>
```

or you can try this http://www.ubercart.org/comment/60577

Comment: source http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/4037/stock_level_product_page

Comment: uc_stock_skus is a drupal5 function.

Comment: @Ram try to convert this function for drupal 7, since no other way to find the proper one.

Comment: This is just printing the stock level, but i want to print also how many has been already purchased.

Comment: I just have a doubt. Why is tat fetaure of stock is coming only while editing a product, not while adding a product?

Answer (score 0):

```
         <?php
                $array_sku = uc_product_get_models($node->nid, FALSE);          
                foreach ($array_sku as $sku) {
                    $stock_level = uc_stock_level($sku);
                    //$stock_count = db_select('uc_order_products', 'up')->fields('up', array('nid'))->condition('up.model', $sku, '=')->execute()->rowCount();

                    $stock_counts = db_select('uc_order_products', 'up')
                                    ->fields('up', array('nid','qty'))
                                    ->condition('up.model', $sku, '=')
                                    ->execute()
                                    ->fetchAll();
                    $quantity_count = 0;
                    if(isset($stock_counts))
                    {   
                        foreach($stock_counts as $stock_count )
                        {
                            $quantity_count += $stock_count->qty;
                        }   
                    }
                    $total = $stock_level +  $quantity_count;
                    if($total == 0){
                        $total = 1;
                    }           
                    $output .= $total . " / " . $quantity_count . " Sold out";          
                }
          ?>
```

This will output exact stock level and sold level of the product.