# How do I configure the Stock module in and know how many products are sold out of stock?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I have installed the Stock module, but I don't know how to configure or include that to my product content type, nor do I know how to use it.

Do you have any idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the below step:

- Go to  Content management -> Content
- Filter content for content type "Product"
- Edit your product content
- Click on "stock" link in top of page
- Set the "Stock" and "Threshold" quantity and check "active" check-box save the form.

**Edit:**

Code snippets to display total and sold item from stock:

```
$output = '';

$array_sku = uc_product_get_models($node->nid, FALSE);

foreach ($array_sku as $sku) {
  $stock_level = uc_stock_level($sku);
  $stock_count = db_select('uc_order_products', 'up')->fields('up', array('nid'))->condition('up.model', $sku, '=')->execute()->rowCount();

  $total = $stock_level +  $stock_count;

  $output .= "<div>SKU:" . $sku . " Total :" . $total . ", Sold out:" . $stock_count . "</div>";

}


print $output;
```

Kindly see that above code will be check stock level for each different `SKU` of the product. If there is attribute of the product and each attribute has different `SKU`, then it will display the `stock` for each `sKU` of the product.

You can add this code in `node--product.tpl.php` file in your theme directory.

Comment: stock is actual quantity of the product. When the stock level drops below the threshold value, you can be notified based on your stock settings.

Comment: @Ram suppose if you have 10 products and you set 2 as threshold and if 8 products were sold, then you will be notified by email like "you reached your threshold".

Comment: @Ram, Yes. You will get this using stock module function, not node module function.

Comment: @Ram Please update your question.

Comment: @Ram, By default, when a product is purchased, Ubercart automatically decrease its stock level quantity and did not save original stock quantity.

Comment: @Ram, I have updated my answer. I will work fine on fresh ubercart installation with stock module.

Comment: @Ram, No. this is default functionality of the ubercart. `Add to cart` or `buy it` button will not display in page.

Comment: @Ram, you do not need to set stock for auction item.

Comment: @Ram, you need to customize ubercart for this. Have you tried anything, please let me know.

Comment: @Ram, you should not update `uc_cart.module`. This is not Drupal standard to modify contrib and core module. Please update your question with your code.

Comment: @Ram, this is default functionality of ubercart stock module.

Comment: @Ram, Yes, there is no way to add it in the add product form. You have to follow the same.

Comment: @Ram, If you have any issue regarding cart page, you can create new question with complete details. I will try my best to answer this.

Comment: @Ram, I am checking for the same. You also need to generate issue in module issue queue.

Comment: After adding the product to the cart page, there is a quantity input textfield where, i can add as many quantity as it is required, but whats the use of stock it not its validating those quantity field in cart page.

Comment: @Ram, Have you tried anything for the same?

Comment: Actually for that add-to-cart button visibility in node.tpl.php i am checking conditon and hiding the add-to-car button according to stock count and quantity count availability. That issue i fixed.

Comment: Only issue now is that in the cart page, where quantity text box field can be added for product quantity be more than stock defined. How to address that.. i hope u understood the issue?

Comment: I have found the other solution also, i.e, Out of Stock Notification module is there , which checks for stock quantity in the cart page. :-)

Comment: @Ram, Ok. I did not search for this.